# How to add unmounting animation with React Motion?

Tags: reactjs, react-motion

I want to add unmounting animation with React-Motion, but I can't found any information about that. This is my code:

```
{this.state.uploading ? (
    <Motion defaultStyle={{ top: 0 }} style={{ top: spring(-150) }}>
    {
        interpolatingStyle => {
            return (<UploadList style={interpolatingStyle} files={uploadingFiles}/>);
        }
    }
    </Motion>
) : ''}
```

animation perfectly working on mounting, but on unmount, it just disappears. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: @Sarmad Nope, not found any.